# How to format datetime values in csv file/column in python?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, csv, replace

I have a csv file which contains several lines and in particular, column sending time. I wish to change the timedate formats **from DD/MM/YYYYHH:MM:SS.DDDD** **to** **YYYYMMDD-HH:MM:SS** for all values in column SendingTime.

**CSV Example:**

```
MsgType,CompID,SendingTime    
AR ,SDF,16/08/2021 09:13:13.09934
```

I have found a code snippet on StackOverflow, and I'm trying the following to change the datetime format, however, to no avail and the below error. Any help would be most appreciated?

```
import csv
import re
from datetime import datetime
 
lines = []
# open file as read-only
with open('datetimeissue.csv', "r", newline='') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    # go over all of its rows, and the row's items and change
    # items that match the date format
    for row in reader:
        for i, string in enumerate(row):
            if re.match(r"\d+\/\d+\/\d+ \d+\:\d+\:\d+", string):
                datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(string, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s')
                new_string = datetimeobject.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%h:%m:%s')
                row[i] = new_string
                print("Replaced", string, "with", new_string)
        # save edited, and originally correct ones to new list
        new_row = row
        lines.append(new_row)
 
# write new rows by overwriting original file
with open('mynewoverwritten.csv', "w", newline='') as data:
    writer = csv.writer(data)
    writer.writerows(lines)
```

**Error Extract**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "time.py", line 14, in <module>
    datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(string, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 354, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format)) from None
ValueError: 'h' is a bad directive in format '%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s'
```

Comment: Instead of using regular expressions use one of the many CSV libraries to read the data and save it again with the new format. Most libraries will actually parse the date as well, allowing you to just specify the new format. `YYYYMMDD-HH:MM:SS` is a *very* unusual format that won't be recognized by any application. The standard format for dates is ISO8601 - `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss`

Comment: Hi Kanavos, thats one of the issues - I cannot install "third party" libraries on our RH systems. Otherwise, I'm literally seeing Pandas everywhere for such.

Comment: FYI if you just want to edit the csv and change the datetime format, there's a Notepad++ plug-in that can do that https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint

Comment: thank you for the info - however, I have to automate this process without plugins or third party tools. The given answer is great because I even use it for lists as opposed to CSV file.

Comment: @Panagiotis yes the time format is strange but this is the format send to clients/clearing counter parties. This is a extract from the FIX message so the standard is used between customers I guess.

Comment: FIX isn't a flat file format. It's a message format used by stock exchanges. In its older format each line contains arbitrary fields preceded by a field code. That's the only place where that date format is used. In the "newer" FixML format, XML is used and dates are proper ISO8601 dates. That means that what you posted is most definitely *not* any kind of standard date format by customers. It's only used to communicate with very specific systems and even then only for a very specific version of the protocol. *All* other systems in a brokerage will use ISO8601

Comment: This means that either whoever receives your files will have to convert them, or you'll have to change the format when your customer connects to a system [with one of the many other FIX message encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_Information_eXchange). I'm not saying you should try to persuade them, but you *should* be prepared for the inevitable change requests

Comment: Thanks for the information Panagiotis - sorry this isn’t a fix message format - but derived from network capture. This is related to a reconciliation task so should be fine on the change request part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%H:%M:%S` (capitals) are the format strings for time.  `re` seems unneeded if you know the time column:

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime
 
with open('input.csv', "r", newline='') as inf, \
     open('output.csv', "w", newline='') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    writer.writerow(next(reader)) # copy header
    for row in reader:
        timestamp = datetime.strptime(row[2], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
        row[2] = timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Many thanks @Mark Tolonen. I can confirm this worked.

Answer (score 0):

> ValueError: 'h' is a bad directive in format '%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s'

There's a big hint. The error is either `'h'` or close to it. In this case, it looks like it is the lower case 'h' that is messing you up. Have you tried using `'H'`?

`datetime.strptime(string, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: Hi Helix, I changed time variables to capitals but get the following error now ` datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(string, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%H:%S')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 759, in _parse
    raise source.error(err.msg, len(name) + 1) from None
sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'H' as group 5; was group 4 at position 116 `